# How to notate single-line percussion staff using ABC notation?

Tags: rhythm, percussion, abc-notation

I want to have this effect by using ABC notation:

[image: Single-line percussion instruments]

In LilyPond, I can use `\new RhythmicStaff` to create such a staff. What's the equivalent in ABC notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ABC, use `K: perc stafflines=1`. (See [Clefs and Transpositions](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#clefs_and_transposition) in the ABC standard reference.)

For example:

```
X: 1
T: Percussion example
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: perc stafflines = 1
BB B2 B2 B/2B/2B/2B/2 |
```

```
X: 1
T: Percussion example
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: perc stafflines = 1
BB B2 B2 B/2B/2B/2B/2 |
```