# ABC notation: percussion / rhythm staff

Tags: abc-notation

Alas, the *Percussion example* [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/124434/how-to-notate-single-line-percussion-staff-using-abc-notation) doesn't work for me:

1. It renders differently, in that it's on a 5- rather than 1-line staff and the clef shows as a single "hollow" box rather than the 2 black lines.
2. More importantly though, it doesn't play. (Other files do play, so my EasyABC is working, as is my system's sound.)

I have EasyABC 1.3.8.6, Windows 10.

Does anyone have any suggestions to get it to work please?

Comment: The hollow box is an alternative percussion clef. The default midi output is probably channel 1 but it might output percussion on channel 10.

Comment: I've tried program 10 @PiedPiper, as well as 9 and 11- I noticed in the past it's sometimes off by 1- no change. Even if the program is wrong and it doesn't sound, shouldn't the note head change to orange when it's played?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EasyABC is a little different to the ABCjs that’s running on this site, so you’ll need to make a few adjustments.

The following works for my setup (EasyABC 1.3.8.1 on macOS Sonoma 14).

#### Staff and Clef

- Set the key signature to something:
  `K:none` (or `K:C`)
- Unfortunately, I don’t think you can change the percussion clef symbol (without changing the music font).
  But, if you’re trying to display a rhythm part (as apposed to an actual percussion part), you might want to remove the clef symbol entirely:
  `clef=none`
- Remove the spaces around the equals sign when declaring the number of staff lines:
  `stafflines=1`

##### Stem direction (optional)

- Set the stem direction in the voice field:
  `V:1 stem=up`

#### MIDI Output

- Send the MIDI output to the percussion channel:
  `%%MIDI channel 10`
- Choose a percussion instrument using standard MIDI percussion mapping numbers.*
  For example: to put Acoustic Snare (`38`) on the middle staff-line (“`B`”):
  `%%MIDI drummap B 38`

### Working Code

```
X:1
T:Percussion example
M:4/4
L:1/8
K:none clef=perc stafflines=1
V:1 stem=up
%%MIDI channel 10
%%MIDI drummap B 38
BB B2 B2 B/2B/2B/2B/2 |
```

---

* Such as table *A.8.2 Percussion Instruments*, as found in Guido Gonzato’s [*Making Music with ABC 2*](https://abcplus.sourceforge.net/abcplus_en.pdf), p. 184.